# Permutations of a list in Python - converting JS solution

Tags: python

I'm converting a working JavaScript solution for for calculating the permutations of an array over to Python, and I wanted to know why the translation doesn't work exactly the same way. Specifically, it appears as though the memo list I'm using to keep track of values is continually appended and never cleared, but I'm unsure as to what differences in Python's underpinnings cause this effect. Here's my code in Python:

```
def perms(input):
  result = []

  def permute(arr, m):
    if len(arr) == 0:
      print('this is m appending!: ', m)
      print('=============================')
      result.append(m)
    else:
      for i in range(len(arr)):
        curr = arr.copy()
        next = curr.pop(i)
        m.append(next)
        print('curr: ', curr)
        print('next: ', next)
        print('m: ', m)
        permute(curr, m)

  print('running')
  permute(input, [])
  return result

answer = perms([1,2,3])
print(answer)
```

and here is the output:

```
running
curr:  [2, 3]next:  1m:  [1]
curr:  [3]
next:  2
m:  [1, 2]
curr:  []
next:  3
m:  [1, 2, 3]
this is m appending!:  [1, 2, 3]
=============================
curr:  [2]
next:  3
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3]
curr:  []
next:  2m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2]this is m appending!:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
=============================
curr:  [1, 3]
next:  2
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2]
curr:  [3]
next:  1
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
curr:  []
next:  3
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3]
this is m appending!:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3]
=============================
curr:  [1]
next:  3
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3]
curr:  []
next:  1
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]
this is m appending!:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]
=============================
curr:  [1, 2]
next:  3
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3]
curr:  [2]
next:  1
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1]
curr:  []
next:  2m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]this is m appending!:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]
=============================
curr:  [1]
next:  2
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2]
curr:  []
next:  1
m:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1]
this is m appending!:  [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1]
=============================
[[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1]]
```

As you can see, the first result ([1,2,3]) is processed as intended (as you can see where I print 'this is m appending' to the results list).However, m fails to "back out" appended items when the recursion steps backwards to execute. I'm assuming this is because Python manages the stack differently, but I'm unsure. If it's helpful, I can also post the JavaScript code and results.

If someone could explain to me why exactly this code is failing, that would be great!

Comment: [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement)

Comment: I think you're right! But how can I declare m as nonlocal in the function definition? When I tried `nonlocal m` prior to appending to m, I got this error: `SyntaxError: name 'm' is parameter and nonlocal`

Comment: Fix: Use `result.append(m.copy())` and add a line `m.pop()` after `permute(curr, m)` for backtracking(to "back out" appended items).

Comment: Oh awesome, so you just back out your `append()` with a `pop()` after the recursive call drills down to the bottom. That works!

Answer (score 0):

Olvin's comment was correct that the issue was caused by nonlocal scoping, and Ajay's comment was a good fix for the problem - basically backing out the changes to the list manually after recursion. Here's the now-functioning code:

```
def perms(input):
  result = []

  def permute(arr, m = []):
    if len(arr) == 0:
      result.append(m.copy())
    else:
      for i in range(len(arr)):
        curr = arr.copy()
        nextItem = curr.pop(i)
        m.append(nextItem)
        permute(curr, m)
        m.pop()

  print('running')
  permute(input)
  return result

answer = perms([1,2,3])
print(answer)
```